# css overflow hidden cause border disappear

Tags: css, overflow, border

I want to render a table with round corner, but also with the single border inside and outside. 
It is odd that table only has round corner when overflow: hidden;
but the borders also disappear. 
So I tried to add border and attempted to use border-collapse: collapse; to tidy up the table, but it seems that "border-collapse: collapse" contradict with the border-radius.

Please see my example.

```
<table >

    <tr>
        <th>Most </th>
        <th>Reasons</th>
        <th>Least</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="most_1">m1</td>
        <td id="reason_1" >reason1</td>
        <td id="least_1">l1</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="most_2">m2</td>
        <td id="reason_2">reason2</td>
        <td id="least_2">l2</td>
    </tr>

table{
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 600px;
border:5px solid black;
border-radius: 10px 40px 40px 10px;      
overflow: hidden;

}
tr, th, td{
    border:5px solid black;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/bosthe75/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying border-radius to table is not a good idea. You can achieve your result for changing your structure like below.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="roundborder">
  <table border="0">        
    <tr>
        <th>Most </th>
        <th>Reasons</th>
        <th>Least</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="most_1">m1</td>
        <td id="reason_1" >reason1</td>
        <td id="least_1">l1</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="most_2">m2</td>
        <td id="reason_2">reason2</td>
        <td id="least_2">l2</td>
    </tr>            
   </table>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .roundborder{
 border:5px solid black;
border-radius: 10px 40px 40px 10px; 
width:600px;
}
.roundborder table{
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 600px;
//overflow: hidden; 
}
.roundborder th, .roundborder td{
border-right:5px solid black;  
border-bottom:5px solid black;
}
.roundborder th:last-child,.roundborder td:last-child
{
 border-right:0px;
}
.roundborder tr:last-child td
{
border-bottom:0px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/bosthe75/6/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your DEMO link is not working any more, so I am keeping this link here for future viewer: http://jsfiddle.net/matildayipan/6aru270p/

Answer (score 0):

I guess `border-radius` is the problem

css

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 600px;
    border:5px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
tr, th, td {
    border:5px solid black;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/bosthe75/4/)

Comment: border-radius is NOT the problem! Because I need it to shape the table corner. Please see the solution above~